# Not able to update child account's custom field when its related parent account's custom field will be updated

Tags: apex, trigger

Create one percentage field on Account with API Name Discount__c. Task : Create one apex trigger on account so that whenever the value of Discount__c field is update on parent account, the same value must be updated on the child accounts of the parent.

Here what i have done till now i'm sharing the code but i'm not able to contain the error

A non foreign key field cannot be referenced in a path expression: ParentId

Here is my code --

```
trigger testAccountTrigger on Account (after update) {
    List<Id> acctId = new List<Id>();
    List<Account> acctToUpdate = new List<Account>();
    for(Account acc : Trigger.new) {
        acctId.add(acc.ParentId);
    }
    for(Account a : [select id,Discount__c from Account where id in: acctId]) 
    {
        for(Account ac : trigger.new) 
        {
            a.Discount__c = ac.ParentId.Discount__c;
            acctToUpdate.add(a);
        }
    }
    if(acctToUpdate.size()>0) {
        update acctToUpdate;
    }
}
```

how to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

This is the pattern I would use here:

```
trigger testAccountTrigger on Account (after update) {
    
    Map<Id, Account> parents = new Map<Id, Account>();

    // Only care about changes to this specific field
    for (Account a : Trigger.new) {
        Account old = Trigger.oldMap.get(a.Id);
        if (a.Discount__c != old.Discount__c) {
            parents.put(a.Id, a);
        }
    }

    if (parents.size() > 0) {

        Account[] updates = new Account[] {};

        // Query the children
        for (Account child : [
            select Id, ParentId, Discount__c
            from Account
            where ParentId in :parents.keySet()
        ]) {
            // Only update if necessary, though probably always necessary
            Decimal parentDiscount = parents.get(child.ParentId).Discount__c;
            if (child.Discount__c != parentDiscount) {
                 child.Discount__c = parentDiscount;
                 updates.add(child);
            }
        }

        update updates;
    }
}
```

Note that this approach could run into trouble for very deep trees i.e. trees that have many layers of parent/child relationships because the `update` will cause the same trigger to be run again per layer.

Comment: getting error while editing parent account                                                                                                                              
testAccountTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Account.ParentId Trigger.testAccountTrigger: line 24, column 1

Comment: @soumyaranjantripathy That field was missing from `select Id, Discount__c`; I've changed it above to `select Id, ParentId, Discount__c`.